# How to get rid of the Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe (LLVM 0x300) driver? INTEL needed

Tags: 12.04, drivers, xorg, intel-graphics, gallium

Ubuntu 12.04 LTS only runs 2D mode after changing MB and CPU. It appears using the wrong video driver: "Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe (LLVM 0x300)" rather than the required "Intel" G43 version from the "xserver-xorg-video-intel" driver package. 
The new motherboard is a MSI Z87-G43 with a i7 CPU.

I tried lots of things and checked out about all I could find on the web. 
I removed the VMware drivers, nvidia en ATI divers and their configuration files without result. Creating an etc/X11/xorg.conf file with "intel" assigned to be used, the system became instable. I even did a fresh Ubuntu 12.04 install on an old HD, finding out that the meant "Intel" driver appeared to be used!

Now I'm stuck!

What should I do to get it right for my existing Ubuntu 12.04 LTS system?

Answer (score 5):

The xserver-xorg-video-intel package provides the basic Xorg driver which is used for 2D drawing, etc. llvmpipe is the software renderer for 3D operations, if you install the libgl1-mesa-dri package, then you should have the *Mesa DRI Intel(r) ...* renderer.

Note that the original drivers shipped with 12.04 are quite old, you are suggested to install the [LTS Enablement Stack](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack) to get more recent versions for the graphics subsystem and kernel.

Comment: I have checked out that the "libgl1-mesa-dri" package is installed. I also tried later versions of the xserver-xorg-video-intel package, without success. I looked in the file "/var/log/Xorg.0.log" to find that the intel module was unloaded, moving on with VESA... No idea!

Comment: @JGMS Perhaps you could paste your post your Xorg.0.log on http://paste.ubuntu.com/? It may contain a hint. Please add the output of `lsmod` to your question as well, and if you want to post another log, run `dmesg > dmesg.txt` and post the contents of it.

Comment: That was truly a great hint! It solved the problem. Many thanks indeed!

Comment: @JGMS It would be nice if you could post the solution to your question here and mark it as accepted.

Comment: **[ACCEPTED ANSWER. PROBLEM SOLVED]** Getting "Intel Haswell" instead of the "Gallium 0.4 llvmpipe" video driver: I very much appreciate the support I got from an export user of Ask Ubuntu. The problem was indeed solved by loading the "LTS Enablement Stack" drivers. I Just followed the link offered by **Lekensteyn** and copied the commands in the terminal. Amazing how simple things can turn out to be in Ubuntu: I love it! JGMS